# Use of Yaesu FT-7800R External Speaker Jack Loss of Audio

Tags: yaesu, equipment-troubleshooting, repair, speaker

I plugged an external speaker into our Yaesu FT-7800R EXT SP jack. As a result, I've lost audio, both when the speaker is plugged in and not plugged in.

A ham told me that the FT-7800R has a known problem from plugging in a speaker and having the audio's output latched to the external speaker, as well as losing audio.

Has anyone heard about this? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I regret my loss of audio was due to cockpit error. I accidentally had the tone squelch engaged; I went back through the CTSS procedure in the manual; and reset everything without tone squelch engaged. Now, the audio is working again.